# Ubuntu won't boot. Detects storage device that isn't there

Tags: boot

[image]

I tried fsck, it says this
[image]

Dpkg does nothing

I entered the shell prompt and did some update,upgrade, autoremove, autoclean, and the problem remains. No external disk is connected to the PC. Pls help.

The version is the latest. Not the LTS, but the latest. In the last running session I had and external disk connected and I remember I installed FUSE, which worked fine.

[image]

Also I removed the last line of fstab which contained this mass storage device, saved and entered reboot. It doesn't boot...

stuck here..
[image]

Managed to make it work finally. I don't really know how. I think I entered the tty terminal (if that's the name) and updated/upgraded/autoremove with internet access. I could do nothing in the 'enable networking' option of the recovery menu.

That's a bad user experience though. The networking, dpkg and fsck options of the recovery menu are useless... And bugs are everywhere.

Comment: please check your /etc/fstab if the device in present there.

Comment: Looks like a record was added to `/etc/fstab` that no longer exists. Perhaps you can edit `fstab` to remove the device that is no longer connected?

Comment: @matigo , @ nobody I removed the last line of fstab manually, see above, it won't boot...

Comment: Is this a new install or did it work previously? If not a new install give specific details about what you did to break it. Not vague textual memories, the actual commands.

Comment: @OrganicMarble no it isn't a new install. Both the OS and the external drive (if that was the problem) were working properly before.

Comment: "*That's a bad user experience though. The networking, dpkg and fsck options of the recovery menu are useless... And bugs are everywhere.*". All the software mentioned in this question is open source. Ubuntu is a community-based project. You already have the ability to contribute fixes for all the  bugs you encountered. You already have the power to contribute improvements to user experience.